# Powershell: Parse and copy multiple times

Tags: powershell, parsing, copy

This command

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*$s*"
```

gives me this result:

```
    Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                  
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                  
-a----        1/21/2018  12:18 PM         337562 001938 H-22 and Note.pdf                   
-a----        1/24/2018   8:48 AM         319382 002104 H-22 and Note.pdf                   
-a----        1/21/2018  12:27 PM         339307 002351 H-22 and Note.pdf                   
-a----        1/24/2018   8:41 AM         338962 002454 H-22 and Note.pdf
```

I want to copy the individual files into multiple files, e.g.:

```
001938 H-22 and Note.pdf
001938 H-22.pdf
001938 Note.pdf
```

3 copies of the same file - original and 2 duplicates.

Question: How can I tersely get the number for each file (e.g., 001938) then copy that file into multiple files (e.g., `001938 22.pdf` and `001938 Note.pdf`)?

I can't seem to find a good starting point for getting the number THEN using that to copy multiple times.

Comment: To get the number into a variable use -Split ' '. Then use that variable to build the path for the copy.

Comment: Your logic will need to capture the number and find the unique matches to that number, and you can work from there.

Comment: @EBGreen I hadn't seen Split before, but it makes sense. Splitting on space would be perfect as I only need the first part.

Answer (score 1):

Example using regular expressions:

```
$fn = "001938 H-22 and Note.pdf"
$fn | Select-String '^([0-9]+) (\S+) and (\S+)(\.pdf)' | ForEach-Object {
  "Copy $fn to {0} {1}{2}" -f
    $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value,
    $_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value,
    $_.Matches[0].Groups[4].Value
  # Outputs 'Copy 001938 H-22 and Note.pdf to 001938 H-22.pdf'
  "Copy $fn to {0} {1}{2}" -f
    $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value,
    $_.Matches[0].Groups[3].Value,
    $_.Matches[0].Groups[4].Value
  # Outputs 'Copy 001938 H-22 and Note.pdf to 001938 Note.pdf'
}
```

Comment: Ahhh... regex. How I hate thee - because of how powerful you are... and yet so very very ugly. Tip of the hat to this one though.

Answer (score 1):

This might be obvious, but if the sections of the file names are fixed length, you could go with straightforward solution:

```
$a = "001938 H-22 and Note.pdf"
$a
$a.substring(0,7) + $a.substring(7,4) + ".pdf" 
$a.substring(0,7) + $a.substring(16)
```

Comment: Not sure this will be applicable, but I can use it in other parts. Substring will be a nice alternative to split or regex.

Answer (score 1):

The following uses the unary form of the `-split` operator to split the base name (filename root) into whitespace-separated tokens and then constructs an array of output filenames from these tokens:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*$s*" | % {
  # Split the base name (filename root) into whitespace-separated tokens.
  # (For separators other than whitespace, use the binary form of -split;
  # e.g., `$_.BaseName -split '_'`)
  $tokens = -split $_.BaseName
  $ext = $_.Extension # save the input extemsion
  # Construct the array of output filenames from the tokens:
  $destNames = 
    $_.Name,                                        # e.g.: 001938 H-22 and Note.pdf
    ('{0} {1}{2}' -f $tokens[0], $tokens[1], $ext), # e.g.: 001938 H-22.pdf
    ('{0} {1}{2}' -f $tokens[0], $tokens[-1], $ext) # e.g.: 001938 Note.pdf
  # Use $destNames to copy the source file to multiple destinations...
  $destNames # for diagnostic purposes, simply output the destination filenames
}
```

Comment: Looks like a good alternative to regex - and should be applicable since so far the files I'm working with are names with spaces.

Comment: @WernerCD: If you have separators other than whitespace, you can use the _binary_ form of `-split`; e.g., `'001938_H-22_and_Note' -split '_'`. Note that `-split`'s RHS is a _regex_, which gives you a lot of flexibility.